# Pronunciation of Roman numerals in the names of monarchs?

Tags: prononciation, nombres

Is Louis XVIII pronounced *Louis dix-huit*, or *Louis dix-huitième* ?

I would assume it is the second, but I have found stranger language differences than that.

Comment: C'est le premier : Louis XVIII (Louis Stanislas Xavier de France) se prononce *Louis dix-huit*

Comment: Did you know his full name off hand?

Comment: Son CV : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVIII

Comment: Utiliser dix-huitième se fait généralement avec le pronom le. Louis le dix-huitième.

Comment: @Antzi C'est vrai, on doit pouvoir trouver ça dans des textes anciens, mais on ne le dit plus vraiment aujourd'hui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Louis dix-huit**

Seul *Premier* est utilisé, sous la forme *Ier*. *François I<sup>er</sup>.*

le second, le troisième est compréhensible, mais pas utilisé habituellement.

Comment: What is *ler* ?

Comment: *"Ier"* is the abbreviation of *"premier"*

Comment: Voilà : On dit "François Ier" (I being the roman numeral for 1) mais c'est une exception. Sinon, on dit "Louis deux" pour Louis II, "Louis quatorze", "Louis seize..." (mais à l'écrit, on utilise toujours les chiffres romains, on n'écrit jamais les nombres en lettres ni en chiffres arabes !).